# HTML embed tag covers div tags in navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a static web site for Computer Networks course. Student can download the homework files with PDF format from the web site, I use the embed tags to show the file online,the question is the embed elements always cover the div tags in navigation bar,the z-index css attribute is useless.So,is there any guys can provide some useful way to solve this problem?Thanks!

my Navagation Bar HMTL is:

```
<div id="Navsun"><a href="NewCourseIntr.html">CourseIntroduction</a>
      <div id="secondnav">
       <ul id="menu">
         <li><a href="Team.html" class="subsun">Team</a></li>          
         <li><a href="TeachFundation.html" class="subsun">Foundation</a></li>
         <li><a href="TeachContent.html" class="subsun">Content</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
```

my css code is:

```
#Navsun:hover #secondnav
{
    display:block;
    z-index:100;/*change the z-index value to avoid covered by embed or flash element*/
}
```

the embed element is:

```
<div id="pdfDiv">
<embed width="99%" height="510px;" src="homework1.pdf" id="PdfShow1" type="application/pdf" style="margin-left:2px;display:block;"/>
</div>
```

the overview of my HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Computer Networks</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
 <!--Navigation bar is here-->
</div>
<div id="pdfDiv">
<embed width="99%" height="510px;" src="homwork1.pdf" id="PdfShow1" type="application/pdf" style="margin-left:2px;display:block;"/>
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the result is like this:
[image]

Comment: ` z-index` css attribute is useless` how can  you tell like this???

Comment: I use the Pseudo-classes to change the div's ‘z-index’ value of the navigation bar dynamically when the mouse is in the div area.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the PDF document in a iframe and put the ifram alongside/ inside a div. Which will give you a control on the div.
Here is an example, http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/iframe-pdf.html